# How to convert color image to gray image using opencv in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, opencv, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am a learner,I want to convert color image to gray image using OpenCV in Django but I'm tired to solve it. when i upload a color image then I show the original image but when I can't convert to gray scale or binary image then show me an error if any possible solutions please shear me. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWY51.jpg)

```
def show(request):
from.models import User
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt, csrf_protect
user=User.objects.all()
p = user[len(user)-1].pic

ptUMat=cv2.cvtColor(p,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
o=cv2.imshow('gray image',pt)

#img= cv2.imread(p)
#plt=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2BGR)
#q=request.FILES['img']
#ima=binary(pic=q)
#ima.save()
print(o.url)
return render(request,'binaryimage.html',{'pic':o.url})
```

Comment: Are you sure "p" is a color image ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood your question, but the easiest way is to use

```
try:
  ptUMat=cv2.cvtColor(p,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
except:
  print("An exception occurred")
  #here you can do whatever user warning you want
```

Comment: the question is how to use opencv in django?

Comment: From what I see here:  https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/11/creating-a-face-detection-api-with-python-and-opencv-in-just-5-minutes/, usage of OpenCV is the same just like in other Python applications.